# Al presionar Enter quiero que dé el resultado en mi calculadora

Tags: javascript, eventos

Buen día, agradezco mucho la ayuda, recién estoy aprendiendo a programar y estoy realizando la siguiente calculadora en JavaScript, al presionar los botones con el mouse y con el teclado todo bien pero no he conseguido que al presionar Enter me muestre el resultado de la operación, he intentado de distintas formas y nada

Les comparto un poco de mi código.

```
const igual = document.getElementById("igual")

//igual con botón
igual.onclick = function (e){
pantalla.value = eval(pantalla.value)
}

//igual con tecla Enter
addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
pantalla.value +=  e.key
if (e.key == "Enter") {
eval(pantalla.value)
}})
```

Comment: No sería sensato que No incluyeras el e.key en pantalla.value si es un enter?

Comment: Si lo hago ya no me aceptaría ninguna tecla, el asunto está en el if

Answer (score 0):

```
const igual = document.getElementById("igual")
igual.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keycode == 13) {
    alert("Enter!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente _qué hace este código_. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolví, solo era una cuestión de orden, fallaba la lógica, lo dejo por si alguien tiene la misma duda que yo mas adelante.

```
const pantalla = document.getElementById('pantalla')
const igual = document.getElementById("igual")

igual.onclick = function (e){
pantalla.value = eval(pantalla.value)
}

function reset() {
pantalla.value = ""
}

//igual con tecla Enter
addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
if (e.key == 'Backspace') {
    reset()
} 
  else if (e.key == "Enter") {
    pantalla.value = eval(pantalla.value)
} 
  else {
    pantalla.value +=  e.key
}})
```